# how can I disassemble a Nand binary file from an iPod nano?

Tags: disassembly, decryption, ipod

Ive got a Nand image in bin format not encrypted armv4, cpu 80 MHz ARM 7TDMI processor it is a iPod nano 1st generation I want to see what calls the Nand makes because it is married to the motherboard. I have IDA Pro the cpu and version say they are supported by ida on their website but I do not see these options in the cpu selection. how would you go about disassembling a Nand dump to figure out how and why the chip is married to the motherboard. Like the iPhone I think you have to flash an identifier to the new Nand for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit ARM ISA is (mostly) backwards compatible so just pick the generic ARM processor, you don’t necessarily have to match it exactly.

Comment: well I used Arm little endian and I found an option for armv4 nd things are making a little more sense but it doesnt seem to be quite there. What cpus might be backwards compatible with 80 MHz ARM 7TDMI PortalPlayer PP5021C "system on a chip"

Comment: Ok that works now its in assembly  and shows all the registers hw can I go farther / where are some resources where I can learn how to fully disassemble. this is the file : https://app.box.com/s/t3k2qk67d82whwasub3fuzg2qbfibytx ive been doing a lot of reading but its always extremely basic and doesnt explain much. should I use different decompiler for assembly?